# 'cucumber' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: cucumber

I have installed the following in a windows 7(x64) environment

1. Rails Installer from the RubySource Website
2. In my gem file I have

   group :cucumber do
   gem 'capybara'
   gem 'cucumber-rails'
   gem 'cucumber'
   gem 'rspec-rails'
   end
3. All of the required gems got installed successfully - no issues at all
4. Even this

**rails generate cucumber:install**

create config/cucumber.yml
create script/cucumber
chmod script/cucumber
create features/step_definitions
create features/support
create features/support/env.rb
exist lib/tasks
create lib/tasks/cucumber.rake
gsub config/database.yml
gsub config/database.yml
force config/database.yml

**When I say "cucumber features\trial.feature" I get this error**

**'cucumber' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

Can someone help me as to why I am getting this error. I don't want to use rake or reinstall everything using Cygwin or something like that.

Thanks

Comment: Can you run other Ruby commands such as `ruby`, `gem`, etc...?

Comment: Yes I can run other commands no issues

Comment: Can you run `gem list -d cucumber` to prove that cucumber is properly installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to execute cucumber in the context of your bundles.

```
bundle exec cucumber features\trial.feature
```